# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{f(i)}$ where $(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Proposition**. Let $(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers, and suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$ converges. Let $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ be a bijection (we assume that $\mathbb N$ excludes zero here). Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{f(i)}$ converges, and in fact we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{f(i)}$$

My attempt:

**Proof.**  We let $S_{N} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i$ and $F_N = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_{f(i)}$. $\{F_N\}$ is increasing and bounded, hence is convergent.

First we show that there is a subsequence $\{S_{g(n)}\}$ such that $S_{g(N)} ≥ F_N$, $\forall N$. We let $g(1) = f(1)$ and $g(N) = \max\bigr(\max\{f(1),f(2),\cdots,f(N)\}, g(N-1)+1\bigr)$ for $N > 1$. One can show that $g(N)$ is an increasing map, thus $\{S_{g(N)}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{S_N\}$. Also, for all $N$, we have

$$F_N ≤ S_{g(N)} \implies \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_N ≤ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} S_{g(N)} =  \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} S_{N}$$

In a similar fashion, we show that that there is a subsequence $\{F_{p(n)}\}$ such that $F_{p(N)} ≥ S_N$. Since $f$ is a bijection, we define $p(1) = f^{-1}(1)$, and for $N > 1$, we let

$$p(N) = \max\{\max\{f^{-1}(1),f^{-1}(2),\cdots,f^{-1}(N)\},p(N-1)+1\}$$

$p(N)$ is a increasing map, hence $\{F_{p(n)}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{F_{n}\}$. Also for all $N$, we have

$$S_N ≤ F_{p(N)} \implies \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} S_N ≤ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_{p(N)} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_N$$

Thus we have

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} S_{N} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_{N}$$

As desired. $\Box$

**Is it correct?**

Comment: As a remark, there's a far simpler and straightforward proof of this fact. It's well known that if a series converges absolutely (which is the case with positive sequences), then the series can be rearranged and will always converge to the same number.

Comment: @zugzug Sure, I knew that my approach (given that it is correct) was unnecessarily complicated. Still curious whether it is correct though. Is it?